# Como usar los indices de una tabla vfp desde c#?

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro, dbase

Lo que intento hacer es que mi consulta sea mas rapida, estoy conectado a la base de datos de AdminPaq, y si me hace la consulta pero se demora como 5 min en hacerla, pero cuando utilizo el indice

```
USE MGW10008 ORDER TAG CFECHA
```

directamente en visual foxpro, esto no me demora ni 3 segundos y en el api tampoco, pero tengo que estarla ejecutando desde vfp, no se si haya alguna forma para hacer esto pero desde una consulta de C#

Hasta ahorita he intentado esto

```
private string latestId()
        {
            string registro = "";
            conectar.ConexionDB();
            conectar.comando.Connection = conectar.miConexion;
            conectar.comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            try
            {
                conectar.comando.CommandText = "SET ORDER TO CFECHA";

                var resultUse = conectar.comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message.ToString();
            }

            try
            {
                conectar.comando.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 CIDDOCUM01 FROM MGW10008 ORDER BY CFECHA DESC";
                OdbcDataReader dataR = conectar.comando.ExecuteReader();

                if (dataR.HasRows)
                {
                    if (dataR.Read())
                    {
                        registro = dataR.GetString(0).ToString().Trim();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message.ToString();
            }

            conectar.miConexion.Close();

            return registro;
        }
```

Este es el metodo de la consulta y me regresa este error

> ERROR
> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]Syntax error or access
> violation

y con este me conecto a las bases de datos (igual y le sirve a alguno)

```
 public static string lruta = @"pathdelserver";
        private string miConexionString = "; Dsn=Visual FoxPro Tables;sourcetype=DBF;exclusive=No;backgroundfetch=Yes;collate=Machine;null=Yes;deleted=Yes;";
        public OdbcConnection miConexion = new OdbcConnection();
        public OdbcCommand comando = new OdbcCommand();
        public OdbcCommand comando2 = new OdbcCommand();
        public OdbcDataReader dataR;

        void RutaDB() => miConexion.ConnectionString = "sourcedb= " + lruta + miConexionString;
        public void ConexionDB()
        {
            if (miConexion.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(miConexion.State);
                try
                {
                    RutaDB();
                    miConexion.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar